# Issue with Loading JSON data from PHP to Knockout

Tags: php, jquery, json, knockout.js

We are making a website using PHP and Knockoutjs. We are able to sent the JSON data using `$.ajax` method in Knockoutjs.

But it is not loading the data requested initially.

PHP code

```
$students = $db->query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE status = 1");
$students_r = array();

while($row = $students->fetch_array()){

  //default student data
  $id = $row['id'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $age = $row['age'];

  //update status
  //its false by default since
  //this is only true if the user clicks
  //on the span
  //$name_update = false;
  // $age_update = false;

  //build the array that will store all the student records
  $students_r[] = array(
    'id' => $id, 'name' => $name, 'age' => $age,

  );
}

echo json_encode($students_r); //convert the array to JSON string
```

and this is actually generating proper json data

```
[
  {"id":"1","name":"monkey d. luffy","age":"15"},
  {"id":"4","name":"son goku","age":"30"},
  {"id":"5","name":"naruto uzumaki","age":"16"},
  {"id":"6","name":"draco","age":"15"},
  {"id":"10","name":"NIklaus MikaelSon","age":"1500"},
  {"id":"16","name":"Elijah","age":"1000"},
  {"id":"19","name":"Chitrank","age":"23"},
  {"id":"20","name":"Rahul","age":"24"}
]
```

Now Knockout comes into play to show this data on the page, So here is the HTML page

```
function RefreshUser(data) {

  this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  this.age = ko.observable(data.age);
};

var personModel = function(id, name, age){
  var self = this; //caching so that it can be accessed later in a different context
  this.id = ko.observable(id); //unique id for the student (auto increment primary key from the database)
  this.name = ko.observable(name); //name of the student
  this.age = ko.observable(age);

  this.nameUpdate = ko.observable(false); //if the name is currently updated
  this.ageUpdate = ko.observable(false); //if the age is currently updated

  //executed if the user clicks on the span for the student name
  this.nameUpdating = function(){
    self.nameUpdate(true); //make nameUpdate equal to true
  };

  //executed if the user clicks on the span for the student age
  this.ageUpdating = function(){
    self.ageUpdate(true); //make ageUpdate equal to true
  };
};

var model = function(){
  var self = this; //cache the current context
  this.person_name = ko.observable(""); //default value for the student name
  this.person_age = ko.observable("");
  this.person_name_focus = ko.observable(true); //if the student name text field has focus
  this.people = ko.observableArray([]); //this will store all the students

  this.createPerson = function(){
    if(self.validatePerson()){ //if the validation succeeded

      //build the data to be submitted to the server
      var person = {'name' : this.person_name(), 'age' : this.person_age()};

      //submit the data to the server        
      $.ajax(
        {
          url: 'refresher_save.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: {'student' : person, 'action' : 'insert'},
          success: function(id){//id is returned from the server

            //push a new record to the student array
            self.people.push(new personModel(id, self.person_name(), self.person_age()));

            self.person_name(""); //empty the text field for the student name
            self.person_age("");
          }
        }
      );

    }else{ //if the validation fails
      alert("Name and age are required and age should be a number!");
    }
  };

  this.validatePerson = function(){
    if(self.person_name() !== "" && self.person_age() != "" && Number(self.person_age()) + 0 == self.person_age()){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  };


  $.getJSON("refresher_save.php", function(userModels) {
    var t = $.map(userModels.people, function(item) {
      console.log("Something");
      return new RefreshUser(item);
    });
    self.people(t);

  });


  this.removePerson = function(person){

    $.post(
      'refresher_save.php',
      {'action' : 'delete', 'student_id' : person.id()},
      function(response){

        //remove the currently selected student from the array
        self.people.remove(person);
      }
    );
  };

  this.updatePerson = function(person){
    //get the student details
    var id = person.id();
    var name = person.name();
    var age = person.age();

    //build the data
    var student = {'id' : id, 'name' : name, 'age' : age};

    //submit to server via POST
    $.post(
      'refresher_save.php',
      {'action' : 'update', 'student' : student}
    );
  };


};

ko.applyBindings(new model());
```

Now here we are using `$.getJSON` to fetch all the JSON records, but it is not displaying the data on the page.

Answer (score 1):

i can see little mistakes for example

> this.people = ko.observableArray([]);

and others you should recheck your code i think they should be self.people..... self.person_age, later in your code you refer to them with self for example here

> self.people.push(new personModel(id,
>   self.person_name(),self.person_age()));

you refer with self thats why the data is not loading you are not refering to the same object people

Comment: `var self = this;` it's a common design pattern, they can differ depending on context but you can't say that they do because of variable name

Comment: Okay but self =this; is not the problem, we use this so that no conflicts occur between knockout's function & javascript's function, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have tried to create something based on a code from two sources (you have them scrambled), which are looking similar but simple are not the same (are not providing correct data).

First you are creating logic duplicity with `RefreshUser()` and `personModel()`. You should to left only `personModel()` as

```
var personModel = function(data){
  var self = this; 

  this.id = ko.observable(data.id); 
  this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  this.age = ko.observable(data.age);
  /* all the rest stays the same */
```

Then in `createPerson()` you should to update that line

```
self.people.push(new personModel(person));
```

Then finaly `$.getJSON` part should to looks like

```
$.getJSON("refresher_save.php", function(allData) {
    var data = $.map(allData, function(item) { return new personModel(item) });
    self.people(data);
});
```

and should be located at the bottom of `model()` view.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your time, but my problem has been been solved, actually in my php script I was passing unused parameters, that cause the problem, when I removed those parameters, it worked and database values loaded when page refreshes. Thank you for your replies. :)